# Log4j and many rollingfileappenders

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender

I have a project that uses multiple log4j 2.11 DailyRollingFileAppenders. Essentially, each client process has its own appender. It's been working fine for years, but now that I've added a few more appenders to the config, it's not respecting the newest appenders and the logging data is getting dumped into the root appender.

I've compared appender configs from ones that work to the new ones, and I'm not messing anything up between them (like forgetting something).

It seems like there's a limit to how many you can have, but I can't seem to find where that's the case. Is there a limit to the number of active appenders you can have? Can it be tweaked?

Here's a snip of the config - but imagine 28 RollingFileAppenders in there:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CON, queue

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.queue=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.queue.File=log/QueueListener.log
log4j.appender.queue.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.queue.MaxBackupIndex=5

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.queue.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.queue.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to CON
log4j.appender.CON=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CON.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CON.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CON.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n

# demo Appender
log4j.appender.demo=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.demo.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.demo.File=log/demo/demo.log
log4j.appender.demo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.demo.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.demo=INFO, CON, demo
log4j.additivity.demo=false

# client_1 Appender
log4j.appender.client_1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.client_1.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.client_1.File=log/client_1/client_1.log
log4j.appender.client_1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.client_1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.client_1=INFO, CON, client_1
log4j.additivity.client_1=false
```

I've seen it where the appenders are also listed on the route definition, but I haven't had to do that before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the appender aliases in `log4j.rootLogger`. So based on your config snip. You should have:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CON, queue, demo, client_1
```

Comment: Thanks jpllosa, that seemed to have worked for a part of it. I do see some root logger pieces showing up in the other appenders now. I know I may have some things not associated with a specific appender and it looks like those items are in everyone's logs and not just in the root logger.